# How to create an instance of Project1.Form from Project2.Form where Project2 is a reference for Project1?

Tags: c#, instance

Let's say I have 2 projects, Project1 and Project2 which have been created separately. I have added Project2 into Project1 as an "Existing Project". Then I have added Project2 as a Reference to Project1.

I can now access anything of Project2 from Project1 by simply creating an Instance of Project2!

Now I need to access Project1 from Project2. But can't create an Instance as I couldn't add Circular Dependency! How can I overcome this type of problem?

**Note: I have added the Project2 Form.cs,Form.Designer.cs,Form.Designer.resx into Project1. But I can't add this Form into Program.cs in Project1 to compile! I have added the both System.Windows.Form and System.Drawing as references to Project1!**

As you can see there are two questions here! Please help!

Thanks and best regards!

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you mean by "I have added Project2 into Project1 as an "Existing Project" - if you mean you've added the source files, that's a really bad idea. Keep the two projects separate, or have *just* one project if the types really need to refer to each other.

Comment: In Project1->Add Existing Project->"Here I have Added the Project2.csproj"

I had to integrate the 2 projects because Project1 is created by me and Project2 is created by my friend using VS 2008! These 2 projects are needed to complete the system!

Comment: I only see "Add Existing Project" at the *solution* level, not the *project* level. Solutions are very different from projects, and you need to be clear which is which.

Comment: I did add it to the Solution Level. I am thinking this easy question occurs to me because of my Visual Studio 2008. Something wrong with it might be..

Comment: Okay, so you didn't add it to the project. I strongly suggest you rewrite your question to make it clearer. But fundamentally, you can't have cyclic references. Maybe if you describe what you're trying to achieve (rather than how you're trying to achieve it) - then we may be able to help you better.

Comment: Okay, I will try to make this much clearer!